# Install Python packages and directories (windows)

Tags: python, package

I am new to configuring and setting up Python from scratch.

I have installed Anaconda and I plan to use Spyder for python development. I also have a older version of Python installed on the same machine elsewhere.

I needed to get my hands on a package to use in Spyder which I needed to download and install.

I downloaded and installed pip directly from the website and then I used this in the command line of the older python install to obtain the package I required.

However I don't understand how I go about making this available to Spyder. I believe it works on a folder structure within it's own directory and I am unsure how to change this to get the package I have already downloaded.

I thought I might be able to copy it across, or point it at the directory where the package was downloaded to but I cannot work out how to do this.

I also tried using pip from within Spyder to work but it cannot find it.

Can you please let me know what I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

from the command line can you use pip? Btw I believe python 3 comes with pip included anyway you need to make sure it's in your path

Find `pip.exe` on your computer, then add its folder (for example, `C:\Python27\Scripts`) to your path (Start / Edit environment variables). Now you should be able to run pip from the command line. Try installing a package:

```
pip install httpie
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

Open Anaconda Prompt and then do:  pip install whatever - to install wheels

If you want to install spyder the open Anaconda Navigator - and you should be in the home tab - then highlat spyder and press install - thats all.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise there was a Anaconda Prompt initially. I set the env variable as the other poster suggested and then used Anaconda prompt to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways but within spyder ipython console you can install package like.

```
In [1]: import pip

In [2]: pip.main(['install', 'module-name'])
```